# Python: how to delete last 10 words from a string column in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I a am new to python. I am using jupyter-notebook for text analysis.
I have a data frame with three columns. I want to delete the last 10 words from each row in the last column (called text). The last words in every row are html information from where the text came, I already have that in a separate columns and just want to delete it.

I tried code I found online, but it doesnt do anything (even if there is no error) it doesnt delete the last word, nor anything else

Code looks like this:

```
df_new = pd.read_csv (r"/Users/shakirashakira/Documents/Term paper/Output_3COLUMNS.csv", sep=';')
```

I have three columns:

```
Source = ["Blic", "N1",...]

Title = ["Potreban dogovor o jednom kandidatu opozicije",   'Topli zec' za radoznale novinare (VIDEO)"...]

Text = ["Predsednik pokreta Dosta je bilo Saša Radul...https://beta.rs/betavideo/betavideo-politika/54473-potreban-dogovor-o-jednom-kandidatu-opozicije", 1487279100000}, "59a0699ae3bcbdee7cc04aa8fd93cc2c34888eac7360a21157f38b4ec395eede",  "beta.rs","beta.rs", "MRMBannedUrlType": null, "Polls": null,"Originality": 0}"]
```

All three columns are string variables. The last column is one big string per row. I want to delete the last 10 words from that one big string.

I tried this to delete the last word in text column

```
df_new.TEXT.str.rsplit(' ',1).str[0]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this?

```
for string in dataframe:
    string=string[:len(string)-10]
```

Please Clarify your question and refer to [asking guidlines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

If the above code is what you are looking for, then feel free to tell me, i will try to explain in the best way i can.

Comment: Yes!! but does this delete the last 10 words in all the data frame or only the last column (TEXT)? If it does, how can I specify so it only deleted last words in the TEXT column? THANK YOU

Comment: See, i dont know about what you code has, you can provide [a Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your code. So i can give you the exact solution. Right now my solution tells you about how to remove 10 letters from the end.

Comment: Edit your question with a snippet, so i can tell you how to do it.

Comment: I edited the question with a bit more information

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code;

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',250)

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Source':['src1', 'src2', 'Src3'],
 'Title':['title1','title2', 'title3'],
 'Text': [' '.join([f'xyz{i}' for i in range(15)]),
          ' '.join([f'klm{i}' for i in range(15)]),
          ' '.join([f'abc{i}' for i in range(15)]),
         ]
}
)
display(df)
df.assign(Text= lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: ' '.join(y.Text.split(' ')[:-10]), axis=1))
```

Comment: hmm can you maybe explain this code? I am not sure I understand it. I get an invalid syntax when I try it

Comment: the only missing line is import pandas as pd, the rest of the code works without any dependency, the screenshot is attached. The first part of the code until the last line produces the dummy dataframe. In the last line, "assign" function inserts a new column with the given name "Text" if not exists or updates if exists. lambda x function allows the modification for the given x which is the df itself, and in lambda y, y.Text is splitted with space char and the items up to the right 10 is returned as the result